# I need help for how to enter digits into my calculator from left to right?

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I have made a calculator in tkinter python. When I want to type in 21, it types 12 because of the way the digits are entered into the entry box. I want to correct that.

I have tried tag-right but it doesn't work for entry label.

"""
Created on Thu Sep 19 17:49:21 2019

@author: Ishita
"""
    x = 0

```
def add_one():
    if(x == 0):
        entry1.insert(0, "1")
    elif(x == 1):
        entry2.insert(0, "1")

.
.
.
.
def next_num():
    global x
    x = 1

def add_num():
    result["text"] = ""
    num1 = entry1.get()
    num2 = entry2.get()
    output = int(num1) + int(num2)
    result["text"] = str(output)
.
.
.
.
def clear_nums():
    entry1.delete(0, "end")
    entry2.delete(0, "end")
    result["text"] = ""
    global x
    x = 0

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

calc = tk.Tk()
calc.title("Basic Calculator")
calc.geometry("300x600")
calc.config(background="white")

mainframe1 = tk.Frame(calc)
mainframe1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(mainframe1, width=3, background="white", font="Times 20")
entry1.insert("end", " ")
entry1.configure(justify="right")
entry2 = tk.Entry(mainframe1, width=3, background="white", font="TImes 20")
entry2.insert("end", " ")
entry2.configure(justify="right")
result = tk.Label(mainframe1, width=3, font="Times 20")


button1 = tk.Button(mainframe1, height=2, width=4, background="white", text="1", font="Times 20", command=add_one)

calc.mainloop()
```

On typing 1 and 2, the entry box should give 12 but it gives 21. The numerical entries are happening with the numbers on the application(not with keyboard).

Comment: `entry1.insert("end", "1")`.

Comment: Read [The Tkinter Entry Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert values at the end of the entry, you need to specify "end" (or the constant `END` from tkinter) instead of zero:

```
def add_one():
    if(x == 0):
        entry1.insert("end", "1")
    elif(x == 1):
        entry2.insert("end", "1")
```